# Creating complex source code editing control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am wondering if anyone has any experience in creating a new control based on a WPF text box that could support syntax highlighting, line numbers, etc.

Any links or advice on how i could begin creating something like this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there.  I don't have any personal experience implementing something like you're suggesting, but I found a couple of links that might help you out.

- [Derived rich text box with syntax highlighting](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2005/05/VBNET-Syntax-Highlighting-in-a-RichTextBox-control.aspx)
- [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/Opensource/SD/) (it's open source and you can probably grab some insights from their source code for syntax highlighting)
- [Syntax highlighting in a Coacoa app](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ImplementSyntaxHighlighting) (maybe glean some approaches from this)

Comment: i found the AvalonEdit control from the SharpDevelop 4 alpha works great, was able to add it to my project and had it up and running in minutes. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

This should help you to start [WPF Syntax Highlighting in RichTextBox](http://khason.net/blog/richtextbox-syntax-highlighting/)